# flatbuffer unio only generate enum

Tags: c++, c++11, serialization, unions, flatbuffers

I have a flatbuffer schema file:

```
namespace market;

enum MessageType : ubyte {
    Null = 0,
    MarketDate = 1,
    MarketInfo,
}

table MarketDate {
    date           : string;
}

table MarketInfo {
        marketID           : string;
        marketName         : string;
        marketType         : byte;
}

union MessageData {
    marketDate           :     MarketDate,
    marketInfo           :     MarketInfo,
}

table Message {
    type        : MessageType;
    data        : MessageData;
}

root_type Message;
```

When I generate the access files for c++, with

```
flatc -c --scoped-enums market.fbs
```

The output does not have any code to construct and store `MessageData`, it only generates an enum. The generated `market_generated.h` is at http://sprunge.us/lTfX0H.

I read from the internet that union would generate at least something like: `struct MessageDataUnion` and `createMessageDataDirect` or similar, but in my case it generate nothing like this, is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

You create the union by initializing the `data` field in `Message`. This actually generates two fields in C++, `data` and `data_type`. You thus don't need the `type` field nor the `MessageType` enum.. that is already included in the union.

You should be able to call something like `fbb.Finish(CreateMessage(fbb, MessageData_marketDate, CreateMarketDate(fbb, fbb.CreateString("my date"))))` (not tested).